# how do I refresh my wired ethernet connection from command line?

Tags: networking, command-line, network-manager

What is the command line equivalent of unchecking "Enable Networking" (disabling networking) and then re-enabling?

In my environment, there are multiple networks which require me to physically move my  network cable.  Sometimes my connection does not refresh properly, so I disable/re-enable networking to refresh my connection.  Being able to do this from the command line would be much more efficient for me.

I'm using 12.04 LTS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd use the [`nmcli`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/nmcli.1.html) commands for that purpose:

```
nmcli nm enable false && nmcli nm enable true
```

man page:

```
DESCRIPTION
       nmcli is a command‐line tool for controlling NetworkManager and report‐
       ing on its status.  It is not meant as a full replacement for nm‐applet
       or other similar clients but as a complementary utility to those pro‐
       grams.  The main usage for nmcli is on servers, headless machines or
       for power users who prefer the command line.

       [...]

  nm     NetworkManager
          Use this object to inquire and change state of NetworkManager.

         [...]

          enable [true|false]
                 Get networking‐enabled status or enable/disable network‐
                 ing by NetworkManager.  All interfaces managed by Net‐
                 workManager are deactivated when networking has been dis‐
                 abled.
                 Reference to D‐Bus:
                 interface: org.freedesktop.NetworkManager
                 method:    Enable
                 arguments: TRUE or FALSE
```

Comment: chose this answer since sudo not required, saving me some time.  Thanks!

Comment: there's no more a `nm` object as of late 2023.

Answer (score 10):

You can try:

```
nmcli connection reload
```

It will reload all connection files from disk.

Comment: Thanks. This avoids disconnects of other connections and is way less disruptive than a full service restart. Perfect! 

Comment: this also works when changing files from `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/*`

Answer (score 6):

Please try:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Comment: It helps me to do the last step with my `Asus PCE-N53 card`. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You could try ifdown and ifup to disable and then enable the interface. Assiming the name is eth0:

```
sudo ifdown eth0
sudo ifup eth0
```

If the problem is reassigning an IP to the interface and you don't want to bring it down completely, you can just request a new one with dhclient:

```
sudo dhclient eth0
```

Answer (score 2):

To reload all connection files from the disk (for instance after updating the vpn password), you can simply `sudo nmcli c reload`

Answer (score 0):

Best commands in my opinion:

They disables network manager off and on. It is an exact equivalent of unchecking enable networking, and re-checking it to regain connectivity.-

`nmcli networking off`
hit<kbd>enter</kbd>

[image]

`nmcli networking on`
hit <kbd>enter</kbd>

[image]

Hope this helps.

Cheers!.-